# correct layout of format

Tags: python, string, format

So I wrote some code and then found out there's an easier way to do it using the format() function.
My code is

```
r = int(input("Please enter a number "))
c = int(input("Please enter a number "))
numberLength=len(str(r**c))
for i in range(1,r+1):
    for j in range(1,c+1):
        currentNumber = len(str(i**j))
        print(" "*((numberLength-currentNumber)+1),end="")
        print((i**j),end="")       
    print('')
```

but using the format() function is more concise but I can't get the format of format right.

```
r = int(input("Please enter a number "))
c = int(input("Please enter a number "))
numberLength=len(str(r**c))
for i in range(1,r+1):
    for j in range(1,c+1):
        currentNumber = i**j
        {0:>{1}}.format(currentNumber ,numberLength)
```

if you run the first snippet you'll see what I'm trying to achieve. The gap between each number in the table is dependent on the highest number in the program. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `end=' '`, be default python uses a new line that's why all the numbers were printed on new lines. And when the nested loop ends use a blank `print()` to introduce a new line.

```
for i in range(1,r+1):
    for j in range(1,c+1):
        currentNumber = i**j
        print ("{0:>{1}}".format(currentNumber ,numberLength), end=' ')
    print()
```

**Demo:**

```
Please enter a number 5
Please enter a number 5
   1    1    1    1    1 
   2    4    8   16   32 
   3    9   27   81  243 
   4   16   64  256 1024 
   5   25  125  625 3125
```

Comment: Ahh! So I was almost right, just some brackets in the wrong place. Thank you mate!